# how to give the padding from top in Gridlayout drawbletop

Tags: android, android-xml, android-gridlayout

i want to give the margin of drawabletop in grid-layout button]

can any one tell me how can i give the margin of my draw-able icon from the top of my button

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnCount="1" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/commands"
                android:text="@string/aten_word" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/gps"
                android:text="@string/gps_setup" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </GridLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

For approaching your `Drawable` from the text of your `TextView`, use the attribute `android:drawablePadding` and apply a negative value.

To set a padding on top on your Button, use `android:paddingTop` attribute.

In conjunction, these two attributes make your layout look like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnCount="1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawablePadding="-40dp"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/commands"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:text="@string/aten_word" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawablePadding="-40dp"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/gps"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:text="@string/gps_setup" />
    </LinearLayout>
</GridLayout>
```